# run spark-sql user spark-shell,Exception throw out [Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "id" does not exist.]

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, left-join

first,create a dataset with the spark-sql command:

```scala
spark.sql("select id ,a.userid,regexp_replace(b.tradeno,',','|') as TradeNo
,Amount ,TradeType ,TxTypeId
,regexp_replace(title,',','|') as title
,status ,tradetime ,TradeStatus
,regexp_replace(otherside,',','') as otherside
from
(
    select userid 
    from tableA
    where daykey='2018-10-30'
    group by userid
) a 
left join tableb b
on a.userid=b.userid 
where b.userid is not null")
```

**the result is:**

```
dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, userid: int ... 9 more fields]
```

then,export the dataset as csv with command:

```scala
dataset.coalesce(40).write.option("delimiter", ",").option("charset", "utf-8").csv("/binlog_test/mycsv.excel")
```

as spark task running,the following error occurs:

**Driver stacktrace:**

> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1430)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1417)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1417)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:797)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:797)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:797)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1645)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1600)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1589)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:623)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1930)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1943)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1963)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:127)
>         ... 69 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "id" does not exist.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:290)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$fieldIndex$1.apply(StructType.scala:290)
>         at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
>         at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.fieldIndex(StructType.scala:289)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcRelation$$anonfun$6.apply(OrcFileFormat.scala:308)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcRelation$$anonfun$6.apply(OrcFileFormat.scala:308)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>         at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:96)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.map(StructType.scala:96)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcRelation$.setRequiredColumns(OrcFileFormat.scala:308)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(OrcFileFormat.scala:140)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc.OrcFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$2.apply(OrcFileFormat.scala:129)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:138)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:122)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:168)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
>         at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
>         at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:325)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

but, when i directly execute the join operate use hive, and create a new table with the join result, finally export the dataset with the spark-sql command ahead, all going well.

Comment: Can you fix the code?